# Inject character between substring of a string in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a list of words stored in a list, words.

`private String[] words = new String[]{"world", "you"};`

I then have a string, helloWorld

`private String helloWorld = "Hello world how are you?";`

I would like to create a function that will take a string (in this case, helloWorld) and it will look case-insensitively to see if any of the strings in the `words` list are present. If there is, it will put a `*` character in between each letter of the matching string.

E.g. the output would be

`Hello w*o*r*l*d how are y*o*u?` since both `world` and `you` are in the list.

Passing `"Hello"` would simply return back the unmodified string `"Hello"` because there is nothing in the string that is inside `words`.

How would I go about doing this? I have tried hardcoding a .replaceAll() call on the string for each word, but then I lose the casing of the string. E.g. `"Hello world how are you?"` became `"hello w*o*r*l*d how are y*o*u?"`

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: You can use String.equalsIgnoreCase() and check every work (spaces break up words). then simply remove matching words and replace them with m * a * r * k * e * d words.

Comment: I think this question is not about a language feature but rather it looks like this kind of questions to get someone else get the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
private static String[] words = new String[]{"world", "you"};
private static String helloWorld = "Hello world how are you?";

public static String getHello() {
    String s = helloWorld;
    for (String word : words) {
        int index = s.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase());
        if (index >= 0) {
            String w = s.substring(index, index + word.length());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(s.substring(0, index));
            for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++) {
                sb.append(w.charAt(i));
                if (i < w.length() - 1)
                    sb.append("*");
            }
            sb.append(s.substring(index + w.length()));
            s = sb.toString();
        }
    }
    return s;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getHello());
}
```

prints:

```
Hello w*o*r*l*d how are y*o*u?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      String  helloWorld = "hello world  how are you ";
      String[] words = new String[]{"world", "you"};


         String newWord = "";
         String words1[]= helloWorld.split(" ");
 for (int i = 0;i< words.length;i++){

    for (int j=0;j<words1.length;j++){

           if (words1[j].equals(words[i])){

               for (int k = 0 ; k < words1[j].length(); k++){
                  char character = words1[j].charAt(k);
                  newWord+=character;
                  newWord += "*";
           }
               words1[j] = newWord;
               newWord= "";

        }



   }

}
String str = Arrays.toString(words1);
System.out.println(str);
```

}